# How to create time series chart for my data?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Elasticsearch 6 and Kibana 6. This is my index:

```
PUT /myindex
{
    "mappings": {
      "mydoctype": {
        "properties": {
          "Datetime": {
            "type":"date"
          },
          "Vehicle": {
            "type":"keyword"
          },
          "Producer": {
            "type":"keyword"
          },
          "Price": {
            "type":"double"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Datetime is given as ISO time. This is some sample content:

```
{
  "took": 9,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 240,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mydoctype",
        "_id": "1515874730_31",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "Datetime": "2018-01-13T21:18:26.953748",
          "Vehicle": "M1",
          "Producer": "XXX",
          "Price": 20000.00
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mydoctype",
        "_id": "1515874730_67",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "Datetime": "2018-01-13T22:10:00.346799",
          "Vehicle": "M1",
          "Producer": "XXX",
          "Price": 21000.00
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to create a simple time series chart that would should how Price is changing over last 24 hours (average per each hour).

How can I do it using Timelion or other chart? Which expression should I use in Timelion?
I just see a straight line at Y=0. However, I expect to see `Price` on Y axis and hours (0..24) on X axis.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in Visualization. Y axis aggregation should be Average, Field should be Price, then add an X-axis bucket with Date histogram aggregation. That should give you what you need if it's okay not to use Timelion.
In Timelion I used this:

```
.es(q=*, metric='avg:Price')
```

I set the time window in the top right corner, but I'm sure you can set it in the query.